# What is the distance of Earth from the 7 planets, moons and the Sun at a point of time?

Tags: planet, earth, distances

I wanted to know the distance of the 7 planets (Mercury, Mars, Venus, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune ) each (or at least 5 planets) from the earth and the angle that it will make with a line connecting the centers of earth and the respective planet at a *point of time*. Also I need the same for the earth and moon system and sun and earth as they are big influences. At point of time because in the course of revolution of planets the distances with respect to earth will vary.

Being an engineering student I have the wish :) to calculate the mechanical forces acting on the earth at a point of time due to nearby heavenly bodies.

Basically I need the data or in case someone already attempted to calculate the force components I would be delighted to look at it.

Comment: perhaps it will not have that great influence on earth, main influences will be sun, moon, jupiter, mercury, mars, venus and sun I think. And it can be a good starting point for me. i read the wikepedia article, i notice its not a planet but a dwarf planet. Just mentioned as were taught in school like that :)

Comment: Horizons http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi is the canonical way to do this.

Comment: @barrycarter seems to be quite some data date wise. it could be great if you can add this comment as an answer.

Comment: Go ahead and give the other answerer credit, and see also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of sky simulators where you can calculate that information yourself. e.g. Celestia, KStars

Just install one of them and it will tell you position in sky and distance to most known bodies in Solar System, for any given time.

Comment: There are plenty of programs named at http://freeware.intrastar.net/planetarium.htm